# How to split XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath, mule, split

My first post here. I have searched but haven't found what I'm looking for.

I am not really sure what technique I need to do the following.

I use Mule 3.3 CE and I need to split XML files. I need to keep the "rootElement" and its attributes in each and every splitted XML. All XML-files will be dropped in the same JMS Queue.

I know how to split the three Product-nodes but how can I keep the "rootElement" on each an every XML-file?

XPath? XSLT? DOM and remove and add nodes?
I would prefer just an XPath but does it have the strength to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rootElement xmlns="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3"
           preOrderTo="2012-12-31T23:59:59"
           currency="GBP"
           timeStamp="2012-08-15T23:59:59">
  <Product
             itemID="09999-3-"
             name="Plate"
             description="Plate of blue man"
             tax="0.00"
             eanCode="1234567890123"
             eanType="EAN 13"/>
  <priceBracket quantity="1"
            price="10.98"
            grossPrice="13.00"/>
  <Product
             itemID="12345-3-"
             name="Plate"
             description="Plate of black man"
             tax="0.00"
             eanCode="1234569870123"
             eanType="EAN 13"/>
  <priceBracket quantity="1"
            price="15.98"
            grossPrice="18.00"/>
  <Product
             itemID="98765-3-"
             name="Plate"
             description="Plate of yellow man"
             tax="0.00"
             eanCode="7894567890123"
             eanType="EAN 13"/>
  <priceBracket quantity="1"
            price="20.98"
            grossPrice="24.00"/>
</rootElement>
```

What I need in Mule 3.3 CE is the following split:

1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rootElement xmlns="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3"
           preOrderTo="2012-12-31T23:59:59"
           currency="GBP"
           timeStamp="2012-08-15T23:59:59">
<Product
             itemID="09999-3-"
             name="Plate"
             description="Plate of blue man"
             tax="0.00"
             eanCode="1234567890123"
             eanType="EAN 13"/>
<priceBracket quantity="1"
            price="10.98"
            grossPrice="13.00"/>
</rootElement>
```

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rootElement xmlns="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3"
           preOrderTo="2012-12-31T23:59:59"
           currency="GBP"
           timeStamp="2012-08-15T23:59:59">
  <Product
             itemID="12345-3-"
             name="Plate"
             description="Plate of black man"
             tax="0.00"
             eanCode="1234569870123"
             eanType="EAN 13"/>
  <priceBracket quantity="1"
            price="15.98"
            grossPrice="18.00"/>
</rootElement>
```

3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rootElement xmlns="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3"
           preOrderTo="2012-12-31T23:59:59"
           currency="GBP"
           timeStamp="2012-08-15T23:59:59">
  <Product
             itemID="98765-3-"
             name="Plate"
             description="Plate of yellow man"
             tax="0.00"
             eanCode="7894567890123"
             eanType="EAN 13"/>
  <priceBracket quantity="1"
            price="20.98"
            grossPrice="24.00"/>
</rootElement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, here's one way...

**XML Input**

```
<rootElement xmlns="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3"
    preOrderTo="2012-12-31T23:59:59"
    currency="GBP"
    timeStamp="2012-08-15T23:59:59">
    <Product
        itemID="09999-3-"
        name="Plate"
        description="Plate of blue man"
        tax="0.00"
        eanCode="1234567890123"
        eanType="EAN 13"/>
    <priceBracket quantity="1"
        price="10.98"
        grossPrice="13.00"/>
    <Product
        itemID="12345-3-"
        name="Plate"
        description="Plate of black man"
        tax="0.00"
        eanCode="1234569870123"
        eanType="EAN 13"/>
    <priceBracket quantity="1"
        price="15.98"
        grossPrice="18.00"/>
    <Product
        itemID="98765-3-"
        name="Plate"
        description="Plate of yellow man"
        tax="0.00"
        eanCode="7894567890123"
        eanType="EAN 13"/>
    <priceBracket quantity="1"
        price="20.98"
        grossPrice="24.00"/>
</rootElement>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xpath-default-namespace="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <xsl:result-document href="{@itemID}.xml">
            <xsl:element name="{/*/name()}" 
                namespace="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/*/@*|.|following-sibling::priceBracket[1]"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resulting XML files (name based on itemID of Product, but could be changed easily)...

**09999-3-.xml**

```
<rootElement xmlns="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3"
             preOrderTo="2012-12-31T23:59:59"
             currency="GBP"
             timeStamp="2012-08-15T23:59:59">
   <Product itemID="09999-3-"
            name="Plate"
            description="Plate of blue man"
            tax="0.00"
            eanCode="1234567890123"
            eanType="EAN 13"/>
   <priceBracket quantity="1" price="10.98" grossPrice="13.00"/>
</rootElement>
```

**12345-3-.xml**

```
<rootElement xmlns="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3"
             preOrderTo="2012-12-31T23:59:59"
             currency="GBP"
             timeStamp="2012-08-15T23:59:59">
   <Product itemID="12345-3-"
            name="Plate"
            description="Plate of black man"
            tax="0.00"
            eanCode="1234569870123"
            eanType="EAN 13"/>
   <priceBracket quantity="1" price="15.98" grossPrice="18.00"/>
</rootElement>
```

**98765-3-.xml**

```
<rootElement xmlns="http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3"
             preOrderTo="2012-12-31T23:59:59"
             currency="GBP"
             timeStamp="2012-08-15T23:59:59">
   <Product itemID="98765-3-"
            name="Plate"
            description="Plate of yellow man"
            tax="0.00"
            eanCode="7894567890123"
            eanType="EAN 13"/>
   <priceBracket quantity="1" price="20.98" grossPrice="24.00"/>
</rootElement>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Any other possible solution without XSLT? Anyone?

Comment: @ZiggyStardust I'm curious: how do you handle the multiple output produced by the XSL-T in your flow? Do you reload the files from the file system after the transformation is done? If so do you generate unique file names? Or does this all happen in memory?

Comment: Hi David, my thought exactly. Strategy not decided yet. How can I receive the split files into my flow again. Or should I just have a "Folderwatcher" and grab them in a new Flow? My hopes lie in sending them to a JMS queue instead of out on a file and process as "normal". Possible? It is still too early to say if we need unique filenames. I don't need to store the files for long. So sorry, no real answer for you yet. As it turns out at the moment we're about too skip splitting because we need the complete file as a transaction, (7.5Mb). Sequencing seems to be overdoing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What about XPath to split and then an XSLT transformer to wrap each result with rootElement?

Answer (score 0):

use a splitter component and add root element in set payload

```
<root>#[payload]</root>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code to split your doc with [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net) coding, in about 20 lines of code....

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;
public class simpleSplit {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException, IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", true)) //namespace awareness disabled
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/rootElement/product");
        int i=0,j=1;
        byte[] ba1 = ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>"+
                      "<rootElement xmlns=\"http://Ecommerce.com/schemas/loyalist/3\""+
                      "preOrderTo=\"2012-12-31T23:59:59\""+
                      "currency=\"GBP\""+
                      "timeStamp=\"2012-08-15T23:59:59\">\n").getBytes();
        byte[] ba =   "\n".getBytes();
        byte[] ba2 = "\n</rootElement>".getBytes();
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            FileOutputStream fios = new FileOutputStream("file"+j+".xml");
            fios.write(ba1);//write starting tag
            vn.dumpFragment(fios);// write the product fragment
            fios.write(ba);
            if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING,"priceBracket")){
                // write the priceBracket fragment
                vn.dumpFragment(fios);
                vn.toElement(VTDNav.PREV_SIBLING);
            }
            fios.write(ba2);// write ending tag
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```