# How to split message from flow using spliter in mule esb

Tags: xml, mule, esb

My xml is:

```html
<root>
    <log>
    
        <age>name,order</age>
        <name>tetsMessage</name>
    </log>
    <log>
        <age>name,order</age>
        <name>tetsMessage</name>
    </log> 
     <log>
        <age>name,order</age>
        <name>tetsMessage</name>
    </log>
 
   
</root>
```

how can i use spliter in mule to get   as seperate xml and sent for further transaction in the flow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `splitter` with an XPath MEL expression:

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath('//root/log')]"/>
```

More on MEL and Xpath: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

Comment: Thank you,It works but the problem is root is not coming in the payload what i can do to get the <root> also, Am just getting <log>
    
        <age>name,order</age>
        <name>tetsMessage</name>
    </log> but i need <root><log>
    
        <age>name,order</age>
        <name>tetsMessage</name>
    </log></root>

Comment: you want to add 'root' to each split message? You will need to re-add the root element back in using a transformer etc. Maybe xslt. Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783144/how-to-split-xml

Comment: You can also simply enclose the payload after the split inside a root element. Use a set payload transformer with this expression `#["<root>"+payload+"</root>"]`.

Comment: @RyanCarter your answer is perfect but how do i iterate the splitter <log> output